Will my chances of admission to PhD programs decrease if two of my recommendation letter writers are senior preceptors instead of tenured professors?
I'm applying to Molecular biology, Chemical biology, and Computational bio PhD programs this year. I have a letter of recommendation from my PI (worked in his lab for three years) but am struggling to get letters from other tenured professors.
I have reached out to two professors who I took classes with and they are very famous in our field. A week went by, no response. I sent another reminder today, no response yet (they both have seen the email, one sent an automatic email that said she is traveling and might have a limited bandwidth to respond to emails)
Now, I took a general chemistry course that I TAed for as well and the lecturer (has a PhD and completed a postdoc in 2013) knows me from that course (she was also my supervisor for the TA jobs I had)
I can also ask another lecturer whom I took a biology course with and he was my advisor throughout undergrad (he also has a PhD and completed a postdoc)
But my question is, does the fact that these two people aren't tenured professors/well-known hurt my chances of getting into grad school? I believe the other pieces of my application are strong (GPA: 3.86, one PNAS publication, a senior thesis, TAed Organic Chem, Gen Chem, Stats, Calculus, and Molecular Biology for three years) but I have heard the reputation of letter writers matter a lot in these programs.
I would appreciate any help!

What is a preceptor?

Individuals with a PhD (who have completed a postdoc in the past most of the time) that are the main instructors in a course. In my college, besides the basic science courses, almost all the other science courses are led and taught by preceptors rather than tenured professors

This is a bit of a special case, but if a person holds a PhD and has done a post doc also knows you well, and not just from a single course, then they should be fine as a letter writer (US perspective).
The letter writer needs to be able to predict your success in graduate study and beyond. It is difficult or impossible to do that without their own experience of earning a doctorate. But, holding a PhD suggests that they know what it takes to succeed.
However, one course's worth of experience with you may not be enough. The best writers are people you have worked with over time and have had a chance to get a sophisticated view of your academic "character" and drive.
Also, it is far better to ask for letters in person, not by email. Whenever possible make an office visit to explore the subject. It might even be useful to first ask the person how they think you would do in graduate study. If they hesitate in any way, look elsewhere. A lukewarm letter isn't helpful, especially in US.

Thank you so much for your response! The problem is that the well-known, tenured professors in my schools only teach large introductory classes (luckily, my PI is one so I'm confident that his letter will hold the most weight.) The preceptors I mentioned know me in the context of courses and also my teaching experiences. Since I was only in one lab for my entire undergraduate career, I don't know any other tenured professors who could comment on my research abilities. I truly hope this doesn't lower my chances of getting into a good program

@tm1053  While each case is special, my experience shows that, most likely, the preceptors should be fine as letter writers. Put yourself in the shoes of those who gonna read the letters. To them, what counts most is how informative these letters are. The recommenders' positions not totally irrelevant, but are of a lower importance. Good luck with your applications!

Thank you so much!!! that makes me feel much better. The preceptors actually know me much better than the other two tenured ones so I'm sure the content of their letter will be stronger
